# jQuery/Javascript/AJAX response: passing over string instead of int into a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, int

so I know how to do this normally and have tried putting ' around the int but I'm getting a little confused due to the jumping in and out of quotation marks and it doesn't work so far... here is some javascript code:

```
message+="<td class='yellow' onclick='open_flag("+i+j+")'>";
```

this is in an AJAX response thus the message+= "stuff"; then the message variable is put into a div at the end. so this equates to a table of data that the user can click a cell and it opens up a corresponding div. To do this I pass over the two unique ID's represented here as i and j. this means in HTML on the page it'll look like:

```
<td class=​"yellow" onclick=​"open_flag(11)​">​DATA​</td>​
```

I need the int being passed over to be a string because the unique ID's combine may look like open_flag(01) and the leading 0 won't be passed over this is why I need it to be a string like:

```
<td class=​"yellow" onclick=​"open_flag('11')​">​DATA​</td>​
```

How do I do this with what I have?

Comment: what happens when you do `"<td class='yellow' onclick='open_flag(\""+1+2+"\")'>"`

Comment: Simply use a proper event handler ([`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/)) and the problem will vanish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the quotes.

```
message += "<td class='yellow' onclick='open_flag(\\'"+i+j+"\\')'>";
```

or

```
message += "<td class='yellow' onclick=\"open_flag(\'"+i+j+"\')\">";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
message+="<td class='yellow' onclick=\"open_flag('"+i+j+"')\"><td>"
```

should work

http://jsbin.com/inuLAD/1/

Used " for onclick

Comment: No it won't.  You're closing the onclick attribute after the 1st bracket.

Comment: tried this, it results in: <td class=​"yellow" onclick=​"open_flag(" 03')'>​DATA​</td>​

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
message += "<td class='yellow' onclick='open_flag("+ (i + j) +")'>";
```

You can see the difference in the console here: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/RdQud/)